# What is the difference between experience and knowledge and how could we make use of that in machine learning and AI applications?

Tags: experimental-psychology

Let's suppose that i am a blind person whom never had any experience with sight before. I will also suppose that i have started some courses to learn about the eyes and the way it function with detailed explanation of every single component of the "seeing" process. 
according to previous studies in the field, i will never know " what is to see" until i have a direct experience with that. Building upon that, how could we distinguish experience from knowledge for the application of Artificial Intelligence and machine learning?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see now why would you be able to see later if nothing has changed? It's not part of your capabilities.

So the statement "I will never know what is to see until i have a direct experience with that" isn't actually possible  because you can't have the experience without knowing what it is you're experiencing ... how would you be able to identify something if you have no knowledge of it?

Regardless...
Knowledge is objective - Mary had a little lamb.
Experience is subjective - It was a painful pregnancy.

So if you have no knowledge of baseball and I give you the rules book would you know how to play baseball?

Yep. Would you understand baseball? Nope.

The rules are the knowledge. The playing is the experience - giving context to the information.

Deep Blue beats the best chess players. It has no understanding of chess.